# allow a controller action without authentication in zend 2

Tags: php, cron, zend-framework2, acl

I am new to Zend & working on Zend2, I have cron job functionality to make some automatic notifications. For this the functionality is ready & it was set up in Cron (Linux server).

Now when ever a call is made to these functions they are getting redirected to Login action. Now I should allow these specific notification functions to get rid of this authentication process.

In cakephp we have `$this->Auth->allow('index')` which allows to work without login action. Is there a way to do similar to this in zend 2?

I've a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788973/how-to-exclude-a-controller-action-from-authentication-in-zend-framework) similar to this. But it doesn't say where to mention the action name in the ACL

Comment: Code? We need code...

Comment: What method do you use to place authentication before every controller? There you need to make the exception.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I do it, using custom acl management code:

In my User module, I place the Acl config to manage the access to the resources for 3 differents roles: guest, member, admin.

The module.config.php has the following attribute "acl":

```
'acl' => array(
    'role' => array(
        'guest' => null,
        'member' => array('guest'),
        'admin' => null,
    ),
    // List of modules to apply the ACL. This is how we can specify if we have to protect the pages in our current module.
    'modules' => array(
        'User',
        'Application'
    ),
    'resource_aliases' => array(
        'User\Controller\Account' => 'account',
        ...
    ),
    'resource' => array(
        // resource -> single parent
        'account' => null,
        'log' => null
        ...
    ),
    'allow' => array(
        array('guest', 'log', array('in', 'out')),
        array('guest', 'account', array('register', 'verify', 'recovery', 'verificationprogress')),
        ...
        array('admin', null, null), // the admin can do anything with the accounts
    ),
    'deny' => array(
    ),
    'defaults' => array(
        'guest_role' => 'guest',
        'member_role' => 'member',
        'admin_role' => 'admin',
    ),
)
```

In the onBootstrap method of my Module.php:

```
...
$eventManager = $event->getApplication()->getEventManager();
$eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, array($this, 'protectPage'), -100);
...
```

The protectPage function looks like this:

```
public function protectPage(MvcEvent $event) {
    $match = $event->getRouteMatch();
    if (!$match) {
        //onDispatchError do the job            
    }

    $controller = $match->getParam('controller');
    $action = $match->getParam('action');
    $namespace = $match->getParam('__NAMESPACE__');

    $parts = explode('\\', $namespace);
    $moduleNamespace = $parts[0];

    $services = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
    $config = $services->get('config');

    // check if the current module wants to use the ACL
    $aclModules = $config['acl']['modules'];
    if (!empty($aclModules) && !in_array($moduleNamespace, $aclModules)) {
        return;
    }

    $auth = $services->get('auth');
    $acl = $services->get('acl');

    // get the role of the current user
    $session = new Container("appData");
    $role = "guest";
    if (isset($session->user->role))
        $role = $session->user->role;

    // Get the short name of the controller and use it as resource name
    // Example: User\Controller\Course -> course
    $resourceAliases = $config['acl']['resource_aliases'];
    if (isset($resourceAliases[$controller])) {
        $resource = $resourceAliases[$controller];
    } else {
        $resource = strtolower(substr($controller, strrpos($controller, '\\') + 1));
    }

    // If a resource is not in the ACL add it
    if (!$acl->hasResource($resource)) {
        $acl->addResource($resource);
    }
    try {
        //if the role is allow to pass
        if ($acl->isAllowed($role, $resource, $action)) {                
            //do whatever you need since the use is allowed to access this resource
        }else{
            //send the user to log/in resource
        }
    } catch (AclException $ex) {
        // @todo: log in the warning log the missing resource
    }

}
```

I hope it helps.